# Dynamically search and delete multiple registry entries(both key and value) by batch script

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, windows-registry

I have uninstalled a recent game called "Wolfenstein 2009", but somehow I had to do it manually.

I was able to delete files very easily, but here comes the tricky part.

I have following command to query the Windows 7 64Bit OS Registry for getting all entries having "Wolf" in their key/value:

```
REG Query HKLM\Software /F "Wolf" /S
```

Now I want to delete all these entries either by `for` loop or a direct shortest command which can delete specific found multiple entries in shortest time.

I tried the following command but how to substitute variables in for loop is mystery as I don't do much batch scripting:

```
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('REG Query HKLM\Software /F "Wolf" /S') do (REG DELETE "%KEY%" /v %%a /f)
```

Can anyone help figuring this out ?

Comment: Although I cannot help you with a batch script, If you want to do it via Powershell I would be happy to help.

Comment: Ok I have Powershell installed too, I can give it a shot, please post in  answer.

Comment: The partial key, "wolf", might not be sufficient to exclude a vital key that has "wolf" as part of its name. I would use a tool such as Nirsoft's *RegScanner* to search for any undesired keys and values, select only those relevant, and delete the rest all at once with the tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Powershell (as I said in my comment) try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -path HKLM:\ -Recurse | where { $_.Name -match 'office12'} | Remove-Item -Force
```

Alternatively, you can use [Regscanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) or if you need more power try [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite) along with it.

Comment: I am getting `Requested Registry access is not allowed` and `Permission denied` errors, on all entries

Comment: Do you have admin access on your computer?

Comment: Yes my user is in the Admin group itself, do I need to run Powershell as administrator privilege ?

Comment: Are you running your programs as admin?

Comment: Well when I installed the OS, I installed it by one user only and I haven't created any other user ever since, so I think above this user it will be only `System` user privilege.

Comment: When running programs though, are you right clicking on them and then pressing run as administrator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67543/discussion-between-vicky-dev-and-liam-healy).

Comment: Tried with Powershell as "Run as administrator", but still getting same errors.

Comment: @VickyDev same errors here running as admin. Did you figure out a solution?